# Call Bitly with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, url, url-shortener

I am trying to call the Bitly API with Visual Basic.
I found this website with some code and it implements fine, but won't return a shortened URL.
http://www.coderslexicon.com/bit-ly-class-for-shortening-urls-in-vb-net-and-c/

Can anyone help me?
Its just a textbox with a link which will get shortened if you press a button in VB.
I am very new to Visual Basics and appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Max

Comment: Have you registered you program with bit.ly and got your own oauth token? If you're using the code as is, then you'll be getting a RATE_EXCEEDED error because you're using the author of the original code's oauth token. Have a read at the bit link developer documentation here .. https://dev.bitly.com/ and create yourself an account and add your project here .. https://bitly.com/a/sign_in?rd=%2Fa%2Foauth_apps.

Comment: I replaced the login with my user name and added my API Key. Where does the oauth token go?

Comment: Here I would think -   Public Sub New()
..
        Me.New("bitlyapidemo", "R_0da49e0a9118ff35f52f629d2d71bf07")
..
    End Sub
..

Comment: Aah sorry I meant to use "api key" instead of saying oauth code I think. Sorry.

Comment: Still returns an empty string..

Comment: Hi sorry was out of the house. Under the MessageBox.Show Line add this and let me know what the error is that is displayed in the second message box .. MessageBox.Show(b.ErrorMessage) where b is the name of your bitly object. cheers.

Comment: I am calling the function with:

Dim b As New bitly
        MessageBox.Show(b.shorten("www.google.de"))
        MessageBox.Show(b.ErrorMessage)

Both message Boxes return blank

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to try using "http://www.google.de" as your original string isnt strictly a fully formed url. For some reason, I cant test your code as bit.ly isn't allowing me to set an account up and register my app. Sorry.